# The meaning of leaving someone back [ in American English ]

Tags: meaning, american-english, phrasal-verbs, north-american-english

I just watched a great video (a kind of short documentary) about two educators who strive to afford better education for their students in a college in Red Hook (a neighborhood in Brooklyn).
The video makers made an interview with one of the students' mothers :

> The mother (crying next to her son): *I've never cried like this ... I've cried like this one time ... when I had to **leave** him **back**, and I cried, I cried, I cried, that was the hardest thing in my life, to tell his teacher to **leave** him **back*** ... in third grade [...] I told his teacher to **leave** him **back**, because he was struggling.

I've looked up the meaning of *leaving someone back* on the web but, I didn't find a relevant meaning.
Here is what I think it means :

The expression, *leaving someone back* (in the context of the interview): is to make someone stay in their current grade even if they succeed.

- What do you guys think the meaning is? And is it common to use this "phrasal verb "?

---

You can find the video I saw the phrase used in [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XPlLpS7OvbM&t=8m39s).

Comment: Could you provide the link to the video clip, please? The mother could be referring to leaving her child at kindergarten the first time, she had to leave him with his teachers even though, as a young infant, he was probably upset, which made her cry (because she felt guilty). But it's hard to know for sure without a bit more context.

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA  for your help, I really appreciate it .

Comment: The YouTube video was helpful, to me at least, because the mother said her son was in the third grade when this happened and she told his teacher to "leave him back" because *he was struggling*. The context makes the meaning much clearer. P.S I'm not an AmEng speaker.

Comment: You're right @Mari-LouA , and again thank you for you help.

Comment: Why did you remove the link to the video? That was useful context.

Comment: @terdon The video is a little bit long, so I included the impotent phrase in my question  .

Comment: @terdon I thought it's not allowed to share videos here.

Comment: Of course it is, why not? As long as the question can stand by itself and be understood without the video, adding external references is fine. What we don't want is a question that makes no sense unless we sit through some random video. The way you have it, the question makes sense by itself and the video just adds context, that's fine.

Comment: @terdon Thanks man, you know , I'm new here, so, there's a lot to learn :-)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Leave back** or **hold back** means to make a child repeat a grade in school because of lack of academic progress, or very rarely, because of slow social and emotional development (usually in kindergarten or pre-school). Here's a transcript of an NPR show that uses the terms several times.

https://www.npr.org/2012/05/14/152683322/third-grade-a-pivotal-time-in-students-lives

The two terms are interchangeable, but **hold back** is far more common.
 See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=held%20back%20in%20school%2Cleft%20back%20in%20school&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheld%20back%20in%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20back%20in%20school%3B%2Cc0.) chart below

[image]

There is great debate in the US as to whether there is any merit in doing this, with intensive summer school classes seen as a better alternative by many.

Comment: This is correct, except that holding kids back in kindergarten for social/emotional development is not *very* rare; in some schools (primarily the upper-middle-class ones), it's by far the most common reason why kids repeat a grade. In my kids' school, nearly a quarter either do two years of kindergarten or do an extra year of preschool before kindergarten.

Comment: Looking at the N-gram, I wonder why the use of this phrase has become more common during the second half of the 20th century. Was there a different phrase in use during the first half? Or was there a taboo on talking about it, maybe out of shame?

Comment: This adequately answers the question as it is asked, so I am not planning to make an answer of my own, but I think a *little* more information should be added to this one. Particularly, *in addition* to *hold back*, there is also the phrase *leave behind*. *Leave back* looks like somebody mistakenly mixed the two set phrases together, perhaps because they share a more common general meaning. I'm not entirely sure if *leave behind* has the same meaning here, but it is notably used in a schooling context in the [No Child Left Behind Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Child_Left_Behind_Act).

Comment: @Tonepoet. No, leave behind doesn’t mean leave back. Leave behind means to abandon completely, to stop caring about. Leave back is a synonym for hold back, and the Ngram shows that it was once the more common term (mid-1930s to mid-1950s). The NCLB Act did not prohibiting grade retention.